# npm init is not working on windows commend is completing before entering asking for any inputs for package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, monodevelop, webdriver-io

I am new to node.js. I have recently installed node js vs :08.12 on my machine.
It is successfully installed as I can check from my terminal by typing node -v .
Next step when I am typing "npm init" to configure package.json on git bash.
My command is ended without asking for any input for package.json configuration information.

Please check below image. could you please check and let me know why it is happening and how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: But is there a package.json created? Does it do anything?

Comment: No. No package.json is created at all on the give location

Comment: It is an old version you use. Is there a reason for that? Maybe you can install the latest version. Version 12 is now the latest. What do you see when you enter node -v?

Comment: I see 08.12, Do you see the issues is due to older version.?

Comment: Ok so there is node version installed. It should work. But I would recommend to install the latest version. The old ones are not supported anymore. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: thanks latest version resolved this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
npm init -y
```

insead of

```
npm init
```